# Когда unordered_set выполняет equal функцию?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, stl

Создал свой кастомный key_eq для unordered_set. Но почему то он этот функтор просто не использует. Это какая то особенность неупорядоченного набора или я что то криво сделал?`

```
template <typename T>
class equal_for_me {
public:
    bool operator() (const T & lval,const  T & rval) const {
        if (lval->x_ == rval->x_)
            if (lval->y_ == rval->y_)
                if (lval->z_ == rval->z_) {
                    cout << "is equal" << endl;
                    return 0;
                }
        cout << "is not equal" << endl;
        return 0;
    }
};


int main() {
    unordered_set<shared_ptr<point>,std::hash<shared_ptr<point>>,equal_for_me<shared_ptr<point>>> data;
    data.insert(std::make_shared<point>(13.0,41.0,51.0));
    data.insert(std::make_shared<point>(321.0,33.0,12.0));
    data.insert(std::make_shared<point>(123.0,321.0,31.0));
    data.insert(std::make_shared<point>(12.0,31.0,31.0));
    data.insert(std::make_shared<point>(13.0, 41.0, 51.0));// по хорошему такой элемент уже есть и не должен создаваться дубликат
    for (auto i : data) {
        cout << i << " : " << i->x_ << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему equal_for_me не разу не вызвался?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При вставке `unordered_set` вызывает сравнение на равенство когда происходит коллизия: два элемента хэшируются в один и тот же хэш и, соответственно, попадают в одно и то же "ведро" (bucket).

Но у вас функция хеширования хэширует *значение самого указателя*, а функция сравнения сравнивает содержимое указуемых объектов. Это уже какая-то несуразица.

Так как хэшируется именно *значение указателя*, все ваши вставляемые указатели являются различными с точки зрения `unordered_set`. Скорее всего `std::hash<shared_ptr<point>>` выдает для всех для них разные хэши и они все попадают в разные "ведра" в хэш-таблице. Поэтому никакой необходимости в вызове вашего `equal_for_me` не возникает. То, что в некоторых указуемых `point` хранятся одинаковые значения, никакой роли не играет.

Функтор хэширования должен быть согласован с функтором сравнения. Из равенства по функтору сравнения должно обязательно следовать равенство хэшей. Это требование в вашем случае не выполняется.

Вместо `std::hash<shared_ptr<point>>` вам нужен функтор хэширования *содержимого* вашего `point`. Писать вам его придется самостоятельно.

Comment: Спасибо. Сделал как нужно - работает. Еще и разобрался наконец-то с хеш-таблицами